# How to get filename passed in the upload request using AJAX and Multer

Tags: html, node.js, multer

I have a NodeJS server where I want to upload a file and I'm using the multer middleware, while I use AJAX to send the file over to the server.

I don't want to overwrite the file if it already exists in the server, so my plan is to check for the existence of the file before saving it and throw an error if it exists.

This is my code on the frontend:

```
<body>
  <form id="uploaddat">
    <input type="file" name="dat"/>
  </form>
  <form id="uploadButtonForm">
    <input type="button" value="UPLOAD" onClick="uploadFile()" />
  </form>
  <script>
    uploadFile = () => {
      let fd = new FormData();
      let file = document.forms['uploaddat']['dat'].files[0];
      fd.append('file', file, "filename.dat");

      let token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url.com',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': token
        },
        data: fd,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
      })
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

and this is the backend, using multer:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');

var uploadedFileName = '';
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    // checking and creating uploads folder where files will be uploaded
    var dirPath = './client/uploads/'
    if (!fs.existsSync(dirPath)) {
      var dir = fs.mkdirSync(dirPath);
    }
    cb(null, dirPath + '/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    // file will be accessible in `file` variable
    var fileName = file.originalname;
    uploadedFileName = fileName;
    cb(null, fileName);
  }
});
router.upload = function (req, res, cb) {
  console.log(req.file)
  var upload = multer({
    storage: storage
  }).array('file', 12);
  try{
    let statsObj = fs.statSync("./test.js");
    console.log("File exists! Aborting");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("File does not exist, uploading...")
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        // An error occurred when uploading
        return res.json(err);
      }
      return res.json(uploadedFileName);
    });
  }
};
```

I can upload files without issues and they keep their original names, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around getting the name of the files being uploaded. My goal is to try to find the details of a file with the uploaded file name in the directory ('test.js' is a placeholder) and if it errors I upload the file in the error condition (I know it is probably not the best idea, but I can remember nothing else).